# how to connect some boxes element together with wavy line?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some boxes who sort 3 by 3.
I want to connect them together with wavy line.
I know it is possible to download SVG wavy line and use it between boxes, but is there any idea to do it with CSS or JavaScript and create that lines randomly (it's ok if all lines has same view) ?

This is what I mean :
[image: boxes]

Answer (score -1):

this would be one solution as taken from https://erikmartinjordan.com/style-hr-line-wavy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hr>
</body>
<style>
    hr{
    border: none;
}
hr:after{
    content: '∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿';
    /* Ratio -> font-size/letter-spacing = 6.25 */
    letter-spacing: -9.6px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: if you vote me down please write why